# time stamp of the buffer relative to mach_absolute_time()

Tags: avfoundation

From within my AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate in the captureOutput(_:didOutput:from:) handler, I wish to obtain the time of recording of the first video sample in the buffer relative to mach_absolute_time().

Is this correct?

```
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
                if connection === _videoConnection {

                            var timeBaseInfo = mach_timebase_info_data_t()
                            mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo)
                            samplebufferTime = CMClockConvertHostTimeToSystemUnits(CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)) * UInt64(timeBaseInfo.numer) / UInt64(timeBaseInfo.denom)
                        }
    }
```